# Invalid syntax on python match function

Tags: python

I'm extremely confused about this error. All I'm trying to do is use the match function but I keep getting a syntax error even though I believe there's nothing wrong with this.

Here's my code:

```
def compile(code):
    code_ptr = 0;
    mem_ptr = 0;
    memory = [0] * 1000
    loop = []

    while code_ptr > len(code):
        command = code[code_ptr]
        match command:
            case '>':
                mem_ptr += 1
            case '<':
                mem_ptr -= 1
            case: '+':
                memory[mem_ptr] + 1
            case '-':
                memory[mem_ptr] - 1
        code_ptr += 1

    print(memory)
```

Here's the error:

```
    match command:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm running Python 3.8.5

Comment: Are you on a Python version that *has* `match`?

Comment: Okay, you've edited in 3.8.5, so you're not. `match` is 3.10.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I'm running 3.8.5, which should have match, I think. I've seen it mentioned that it should be available from python 3.1 onwards

Comment: It's new syntax in [python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html) not supported in python 3.8.5

Comment: its in python 3.10 so you would need to upgrade your python to use it.

Comment: A dot in a version number is a separator, not a decimal point. Version 3.10 is not a weird way of writing 3.1; it's 9 minor releases later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the [`match` syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/) is only available as of Python 3.10. There are no `from __future__` tricks or backports to make it work; it's a significant syntax change. So unfortunately the only way to get this syntax is to upgrade your Python version.